# Generate gs1 128 barcode in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gs1-128

I am using barby gem to generate `gs1-128` barcode. I am able to save the barcode in a .png file. Below is the code i am using,

```
def pti_label_preview   
    gtin_no =  params[:gtin_no]    
    barcode = Barby::GS1128.new(gtin_no,'C','12')   
    full_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/barcode.svg"
    File.open(full_path, 'w') { |f| f.write barcode.to_svg(:margin => 3, :xdim => 2, :height => 55) }
    render :text => path
  end
```

I created it by referring [this](https://github.com/toretore/barby). `Barby::GS1128.new(gtin_no,'C','12')` is accepting 3 argument, i want to know what are the 3 values i have to send to create barcode.

I have following values gs1_prefix, item no, check sum value, gtin no, lot no etc. What are the 3 values should i pass to `GS1128` method

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the repo of that gem down and find this.

```
class GS1128 < Code128

  def initialize(data, type, ai)
    self.application_identifier = ai
    super(data, type)
  end
  ...
end
```

So the answer to your question is **the 3 arguments you pass are data, type and ai**

Comment: So "data" is the value i should pass to generate label - am i right. Can you tell me What is "type" and "ai"